# My Action Function is not Working with java script

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

Action Function not working.
My apex code and visualforce page here below-

```
public class BBH_Survey {
    public  String   Survey_res {get;set;}

     Public BBH_Survey()
    {
        CasId='50023000001pb1w';
    }
    Public  static void survey_1(){

     List<case> lstCase=[select id,status ,Survey_fill__c from case where id =:CasId];

              BBH_Surveys__c bbh=new BBH_Surveys__c();
               bbh.CaseId__c=lstCase[0].id;
               bbh.Survey_Response__c= '1';
               insert bbh;


    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="BBH_Survey" sidebar="false" >
<apex:form >
<script>
    function bbh_survey_1()
    {
    survey_1();
    }


</script> 
 <apex:actionFunction name="survey_1" action="{!survey_1}"/>  
    <apex:commandButton value="1" onclick="bbh_survey_1();" styleClass="btn1" />
    </apex:form>
<apex:page>
```

Comment: Your code does not even compile as is. Can you please [edit] your question to include all relevant code? Also, how is it "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke `static` methods from visualforce page. **Only controller variables and methods can be binded to visualforce.**

For this to work, you should change your method as below

```
public  PageReference survey_1(){ 
    List<case> lstCase=[select id,status ,Survey_fill__c 
                        from case where id =:CasId]; 
    BBH_Surveys__c bbh=new BBH_Surveys__c(); 
    bbh.CaseId__c=lstCase[0].id; 
    bbh.Survey_Response__c= '1'; 
    insert bbh; 
    return null;
}
```

Note the `return` type has been changed to `PageReference` and it returns `null`, which will refresh the page. If you don't want your page to refresh, then you will have to add `rerender` attribute to `actionFunction` in `visualforce` page. Also, the keyword `static` is removed from the method.